# Eigen MatrixBase template function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, eigen

I don't know how to fix the following code:

```
template <class Derived, class OtherDerived>
void forw_sub(const MatrixBase<Derived>& L, const MatrixBase<Derived>& b,
              MatrixBase<OtherDerived> const & x) {
    typedef typename Derived::Scalar Scalar;

    MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& x_ = const_cast< MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& >(x);

    for(int i=0; i < L.rows(); i++) {
        Scalar s = b(i);
        for(int j=0; j < i; j++) {
            s -= L(i,j)*x_(j);
        }
        x_(i) = s/L(i,i);
    }
}
```

Which when called:

```
MatrixXd L = Matrix3d::Identity();
VectorXd b = Vector3d::Ones();
VectorXd x = Vector3d::Zero();

forw_sub(L,b,x);
```

generates the error:

```
/home/vision/workspace/sci-comp/test/test_leq.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void LEQ_FORW_SUB_Test::TestBody()’:
/home/vision/workspace/sci-comp/test/test_leq.cpp:15:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘forw_sub(Eigen::MatrixXd&, Eigen::VectorXd&, Eigen::VectorXd&)’
/home/vision/workspace/sci-comp/test/test_leq.cpp:15:16: note: candidate is:
/home/vision/workspace/sci-comp/src/leq/leq.hpp:5:6: note: template<class Derived, class OtherDerived> void forw_sub(const Eigen::MatrixBase<T>&, const Eigen::MatrixBase<T>&, const Eigen::MatrixBase<U>&)
```

compiling with clang generates the error:

```
/home/vision/workspace/sci-comp/test/test_leq.cpp:15:2: error: no matching function for call to 'forw_sub'
    forw_sub(L,b,x);
    ^~~~~~~~
/home/vision/workspace/sci-comp/src/leq/leq.hpp:5:6: note: candidate template ignored: failed template argument
      deduction
```

void forw_sub(const MatrixBase& L, const MatrixBase& b,
     ^
1 error generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration requires L and b to be of the same type while in your case one is a MatrixXd and the other a VectorXd. Proposed solution:

```
template <class DerivedL, class DerivedB, class DerivedX>
void forw_sub(const MatrixBase<DerivedL>& L, const MatrixBase<DerivedB>& b,
              MatrixBase<OtherDerivedX> const & x) { ... }
```